# How can I get the initial values from my dataset for a combined lorentzian and gaussian fit?

Tags: python-3.x

I try to fit data using standard defined functions (Lorentzian & Gaussian) from lmfit package. The program works quite well for some data set but for another one its not able to fit because the initial values doesnt seem right. Is there any algorithm which can extract the initial values from the data set and do some iterations in order to find the best fit?

I tried some common methods like bruethe-force algorithm but the results are not satisfactory and it cost a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to provide a small, complete example script that shows the problem you are having.   How could we know why it works in some cases and not in others?

`lmfit.GaussianModel` and `lmfit.LorentzianModel` both have `guess` methods.  This should work reasonably well data with an isolated peak, working like

```
import lmfit
model = lmfit.models.GaussianModel()
params = model.guess(ydata, x=xdata)
for p in params.values():
    print(p)
result = model.fit(ydata, params, x=xdata)
print(result.fit_report())
```

If the data doesn't have a clear isolated peak, that might not work so well.

If finding the peak(s) is the actual problem, try `scipy.signal.find_peaks`
(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html)or  `peakutils` (https://peakutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).  Either of these should give you a good estimate of the `center` parameter, which is probably the most likely to cause bad fits if a poor initial value is give.